# Event Calendar Suggestions for SharePoint 2013

Tags: web-part, calendar

I am looking for suggestions for a Event calendar webpart or add-ins for our internal team site. I have browsed through the options in the SharePoint app store, but most have a price tag associated with them. We are wanting something that doesn't look so "out of the box", but provides us with similar/better functionality. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look through codeplex.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want to have the weekend in your calendar (as Susan mentioned) this would be the code:

```
<style type="text/css">  
    table.ms-acal-month > tbody > tr > th:nth-of-type(1) {  
        display: none !important;  
    }  

    table.ms-acal-month > tbody > tr > th:nth-of-type(7) {  
        display: none !important;  
    }  

    table.ms-acal-month > tbody > tr > th:nth-of-type(8) {  
        display: none !important;  
    }  

    table.ms-acal-month > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(6) {  
        display: none !important;  
    }  

    table.ms-acal-month > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(7) {  
        display: none !important;  
    }  
</style>
```

To get the weekend displayed, but in grey, this is code for that:

```
<style type="text/css">      
    table.ms-acal-month > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(6) {  
        background-color: #ebebeb !important; 
    }  

    table.ms-acal-month > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(7) {  
        background-color: #ebebeb !important;  
    }  
</style>
```

Also I wrote a while ago something about colored calendar in my blog:
https://afrait.com/blog/color-calendar-and-icons-in-10-easy-steps-en/

And something about a custom title with workflows:
https://afrait.com/blog/custom-title-for-event-in-sharepoint-calendar-de-en/

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you do not like in the standard calendar and what you need in addition to the standard features. The basic idea of SharePoint has always been that it is not perfect, it does not do some things well, but it does a lot of things sufficiently well to be a success platform. The calendar is not exceptional, and it was not improved since version 2003/2007 I believe, but it does the minimum trick.

If you want to spend Zero money at least you should be able to change the appearance with CSS and/or change functionalities with javascript. I haven't come across anything remarkable, that was really showing improvements that was for free. It is all bits and pieces wrote by amateurs through the years to change what they did not like (example that Saturnday and sunday shows, while you might want to have just mon-fri)